# Windows code editor that compiles/inteprets most languages ala CodeRunner?

Tags: windows, coderunner

I was intrigued when I found out about a Mac app called [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/)—a simple code editor that can run whatever code you throw at it without having to install any compilers and offers boilerplates for main functions.

Is there a program like that for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at codepad.org:

http://codepad.org/

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion but it is not what I am looking for